# Can fstab interfere with MTP mounting?

Tags: fstab, swap, tmp, mtp

At some point a few months ago I added a line to the fstab to make the tmp go into ram instead of onto the disk:

```
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,mode=1777,size=10240M 0 0
```

That came from here - https://blog.programster.org/keep-tmp-in-ram

I think that was the only thing I touched in the fstab the first part of it was created by the system and looks like this -

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# systemd generates mount units based on this file, see systemd.mount(5).
# Please run 'systemctl daemon-reload' after making changes here.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/mycomputer--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2bc3cb2d-afe5-2000-bd3e-e4a25552d5cb /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/mycomputer--vg-home /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/mycomputer--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

My Android phone used to always automatically mount itself as MTP to the PC (running Debian Buster), but at some point, it stopped.

I'm not sure if the problem started with a Debian update, but I suspect it may be related to a change in the `fstab` file.

Can anyone provide any insight into this issue?

Comment: MTP mounting could have not been affected by this change.